# Cloudfront access to a s3 file was working, but today I get a 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My uploads and access have worked fine until now, but a file that was uploaded last week to s3 (with a cloudfront distribution added a day later) have just stopped working.  The s3 file is accessible but now I get a 403 error when trying to access it from cloudfront.

Looking at my cloudfront settings, I don't see any settings that denote an expiration.

I have carrierwave configured like so:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'XXX',                        
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'YYY',                        
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',                  
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'dir-uploads'                     
  config.fog_public = true
  config.asset_host = 'https://ZZZ.cloudfront.net'                                   
end
```

Comment: CloudFront does not restrict access to files unless you specifically tell it to do so (by enabling signed URLs), so probably your S3 bucket returns 403 when CloudFront is attempting to fetch files there. Is the file publicly available, if not - did you configure Origin Access Identity properly?

Comment: This was the issue, my S3 bucket was not properly configured.  Thanks Alex.